# Get Fragmentation of a Drive on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, defragment

Can I get statistics about the Fragmentation of a drive on Windows Vista? The Defrag utility only allows me to defrag and adjust the schedule, but I'm missing the statistics that older Windows Versions had...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [auslogics](http://www.auslogics.com/disk-defrag), it's free, gives you the stats and I find it does a better job that windows defrag.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but still upvoting and accepting because it has the one function I *really* want: The ability to defrag a single folder, and it's free - Nice!

Answer (score 4):

Just found it [here](http://www.watchingthenet.com/get-detailed-statistics-by-running-windows-vista-disk-defragmenter-from-the-command-prompt.html). It's required to use the defrag.exe command line tool with Admin permissions.

```
C:\Windows\system32>defrag -a -v f:
Windows Disk Defragmenter
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corp.

Analysis report for volume F: DATA

    Volume size                         = 466 GB
    Cluster size                        = 4 KB
    Used space                          = 461 GB
    Free space                          = 5.08 GB
    Percent free space                  = 1 %

File fragmentation
    Percent file fragmentation          = 35 %
    Total movable files                 = 135,458
    Average file size                   = 4 MB
    Total fragmented files              = 26,288
    Total excess fragments              = 1,324,523
    Average fragments per file          = 11.44
    Total unmovable files               = 4

Free space fragmentation
    Free space                          = 5.08 GB
    Total free space extent             = 14,564
    Average free space per extent       = 366 KB
    Largest free space extent           = 707 MB

Folder fragmentation
    Total folders                       = 8,706
    Fragmented folders                  = 1,778
    Excess folder fragments             = 4,540

Master File Table (MFT) fragmentation
    Total MFT size                      = 224 MB
    MFT record count                    = 139,726
    Percent MFT in use                  = 60
    Total MFT fragments                 = 3

    Note: On NTFS volumes, file fragments larger than 64MB are not
    included in the fragmentation statistics

    You should defragment this volume.
```

Answer (score 2):

[MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/index.html) is the just-released successor to [JkDefrag](http://www.kessels.com/Jkdefrag/). It has an analyze feature that is comparable to that of Windows XP defrag.